# Detect stdout connected to a pipe was closed on the read end in golang

Tags: go

Is there a portable way in Golang to detect that os.Stdout that is connected to a pipe to another process was closed on the read end without writing something to it? I am writing a command line helper that should exit if its stdout was closed because, for example, the process connected to the read end of the pipe exited. For example, when run from a shell like:

```
go run my_helper.go | sleep 1
```

the helper should exit when the sleep process exits closing the read end of the pipe without waiting for explicit kill signal or an input that triggers eventual non-zero write to stdout.

I though I could just poll stdout periodically writing zero-length slices, but it seems Go optimized zero-length writes and did nothing in such cases. I.e.

```
n, err := os.Stdout.Write(nil)
```

returns `0, nil` even if os.Stdout was closed on the read end.

As the code needs to run only on Linux, I can workaround this in principle using `syscall.Select` and waiting for write errors on `os.Stdout`, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: You have to read or write to a pipe to detect the other side closing.

Comment: @JimB - on POSIX one can use select/poll to get notified when the read end is closed. It seems Golang just does not provide access to that functionality in its API and the only workaround is to use unsafe and syscall.Select, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26049

Comment: How do you detect that the read end has been closed?

Comment: I see Rob had the same question as I did, and you answered in the issue tracker. I would double check that you can actually block until you get a `POLLERR` without it returning `POLLOUT` immediately, or without having to fill the kernel buffer for the pipe.

Comment: Ah, the behavior seems to be Linux specific :/ You do get a `POLLERR` immediately. That would be the solution if you need to do it without calling Write.

Comment: @JimB - poll is not provided by syscall with Go on Linux, but epoll is. So https://play.golang.org/p/xjWY-VqtQ60 implemets that wait for pipe close. With it go `run example.go | sleep 1` terminates in 1 second.

Comment: Not that it makes a big difference, but Poll is in [`x/sys/unix`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Poll)